# How to post an image on Google Plus in an Android Application

Tags: android, image, post, camera, google-plus

I have post an image to **Google Plus** account in android application. I take a picture from camera and i want to post it on my google+ account.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify the MediaStore Uri (which looks like **content://media/external/images/media/42**) instead of the absolute path on the file system.

Here's an example that takes an picture with the camera, and fires the ACTION_SEND intent with that image. If the Google+ app is installed, the user will be able to post the image they took from the Google+ app.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
  ...
  static final int IMAGE_REQUEST = 0;

  protected void pickImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_REQUEST);
  }

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST) {
      Uri uri = data.getData();

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      intent.setType("image/png");
      // uri looks like content://media/external/images/media/42
      intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i , "Share"));
    }
  }
}
```